# Reading non structured log file as text file in RStudio

Tags: r

I have a log file that has one log entry per line. I want to read it into RStudio and go trough it line for line to look for IP adresses. However I dont know how to read a file and split in on new line.

What i want is to

1. Read file
2. Loop trough it line for line

RStudio The code I have now:

```
# Read data
data <- readLines("failed_jobs.ibd")
length(data)
data
```

In PHP I would do something like this:

```
$fh = fopen("failed_jobs.ibd", "r");
$data = fread($fh, filesize("failed_jobs.ibd"));
fclose($fh); 

$array = explode("\n", $data);
for($x=0;$x<sizeof($array);$x++){
    $line = $array[$x];
    print("$line");
}
```

Comment: Is `readLines` working for you? Or does that produce an error?
What's your objective in going through the data line-by-line (I don't read PHP unfortunately)? Based on your use-case you likely don't need to write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be the basic structure of what you want, the only disadvantage is it will read all lines into memory but assuming the file is not endless that should be mostly fine

```r
lines <- readLines("failed_jobs.ibd")
for(line in lines){
  print(line)
  # do other things per line here
}
```